# Check for empty a field from all in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have four fields, and I the function to return true if atleast one field has a value, if all fields don't have a value return false, How do I do this?

My try:(this doesn't work like I want)

```
function required_eachinput(){
    result = true;
    $('.myclass').each(function(){
        var $val = $(this).val();
        var ok = $val.each(function(){});
        alert(ok);
        if(!$val){
            $(this).css("background", "#ffc4c4");
            result = false;
        }
        $(this).keyup(function () {
            $(this).closest('form').find('input').css("background", "#FFFFEC");
        })
    });
        return result;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My recommendation is:

```
function required_eachinput(){
    var result = '';
    $('.myclass').each(function(){
        result += $(this).val();
    });
    return result != '';
}
```

What it does basically is to **concatenate** all the values of all 4 fields (could be any number of fields). If the result is not an empty string, it means that at least of one the fields has a value. Otherwise, all are empty.

Comment: @Kate, farsi baladi? kojaee hasti?

Comment: mazandarani hasti, pas chera esmet intorie?

Comment: Hminjori khosham omad gozashtam, zeshte?

Comment: na baba, ey val. hala chera esme dokhtar?

Answer (score 4):

You could filter out empty elements and check whether you have any left or not: http://jsfiddle.net/bbFA6/1/.

```
function required_eachinput() {
    return $(".myclass").filter(function() {
        return $(this).val() !== ""; // only keep non-empty elements
    }).length > 0; // check whether you have any non-empty elements left
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without breaking your code:

```
function required_eachinput(){
    result = false; // Start with false
    $('.myclass').each(function(){
        var $val = $(this).val();
        if($val){
            result = true; // If any is not empty return true
        } else {
            $(this).css("background", "#ffc4c4");
        }
        $(this).keyup(function () {
            $(this).closest('form').find('input').css("background", "#FFFFEC");
        });
    });
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Y U NO USE PLAIN JAVASCRIPT WHEN YOU CAN?

```
function required_eachinput(){
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.myclass');
    for(var i = 0, len = inputs.length; i < len; i++){
        if(inputs[i].value !== ''){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/C7w7J/)

Comment: You can always use plain JvaScript; libraries are just for convenience :)